# CarrierWave to update model?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, carrierwave

CarrierWave is doing an awesome job with ActiveRecord of resizing my images as I upload them - but I'd like to be able to record whether the image is landscape or portrait in my ActiveRecord model as it's being processed - is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [README](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#conditional-versions), you can use the following to determine the orientation of the picture:

```
def landscape?(picture)
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(picture.path)
  image[:width] > image[:height]
end
```

You could use this in a `before_save` on your model, like in [this example](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Store-the-uploaded-file-size-and-content-type) from the CarrierWave wiki, which I've adapted slightly:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :asset, AssetUploader

  before_save :update_asset_attributes

  private

  def update_asset_attributes
    if asset.present? && asset_changed?
      self.landscape = landscape?(asset)
    end
  end

  def landscape?(picture) # ... as above ...
end
```

**Update**: To do it in the uploader, I'm not sure of the best approach. One option might be to write a custom processing method:

```
class AssetUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process :resize => [200, 200]

  private

  def resize(width, height)
    resize_to_limit(width, height) do |image|
      model.landscape = image[:width] > image[:height]
      image
    end
  end
end
```

which takes advantage of the fact that the MiniMagick methods `yield` the image for further processing, so as to avoid loading the image a second time.

Comment: I've given this a shot - it does work, but it requires that I load the image twice, once to resize and once to find the width and height - this seems like a poor use of memory! Is it not possible to get this information from within the uploader, rather than from within the model?

Comment: Yep, it's definitely possible. I've added a possible approach to my answer.

Comment: awe-*i have to write more characters*-some

Answer (score 1):

you can add this method to your uploader file:

```
include CarrierWave::RMagick

def landscape? picture
  if @file
    img = ::Magick::Image::read(@file.file).first
    img.columns > img.rows
  end
end
```